# Flagging history does not add up

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

In my flagging history (on StackOverflow), it says:

```
260  moderator attention flags
10   waiting for review
213  deemed helpful
18   declined
18   disputed
```

10 + 213 + 18 + 18 = 259. What is the missing flag?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, the fine print says "older flags were not recorded helpful/declined", but your first ever flag was raised in April 2013, which isn't very old. When that fine print says old, it means 2010/2011 old.

Comment: Have you flagged any comment ?

Comment: @Kedarnath Yes; but comment flags are shown separately and all my comment flags are accounted for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found the missing flag. It is listed as:

> off-topic – Jason C - Aug 12 '13 at 7:24 - aged away

It was an off-topic flag on a question (before I could make close votes, I guess) that looks like it just expired. The HTML for it shows:

```
<div class="cbt mod-flag"> 
 <span class="revision-comment">off-topic</span> – <a href="/users/616460/jason-c">Jason C</a> 
 <span title="2013-08-12 07:24:14Z" class="relativetime">Aug 12 '13 at 7:24</span>
 <span class="flag-outcome ScheduledTaskInvalidated" title="Oct 12 '13 at 3:00"> aged away </span> 
</div>
```

Which seems to indicate that it expired after 60 days (October 12). Since there's no category in the summary totals for "expired", it doesn't show up in the count.